# C++ unable to assign objects passed as pointer in methods to variable

Tags: c++, pointers, object, i386

I have a class named `MyClass` declared as follows:

```
#pragma once

class Object_Class;

class MyClass
{
   static Object_Class *object;

public:

    static void setObject_Class(Object_Class *var);
};
```

`object` is a private static variable that points to an object of class `Object_Class`. In the implementation file, I am trying do this:

```
void MyClass::setObject_Class(Object_Class *var) {
    object = var;
}
```

However, I am getting a **symbol not found for i386 architecture** error pointing to this assignment. What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this? Is this the best way to pass object and store it in another class variable, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare and initialize storage for static objects:

```
Object_Class *MyClass::object = nullptr;

void MyClass::setObject_Class(Object_Class *var) {
    object = var;
}
```

Comment: It works. Is there any better way of passing objects and storing them in private variables?

Comment: You have static *and* private variable declared here. Is your question about private (instance) variables? Or static (a.k.a. class) variables...

Comment: Umm, private static variables? Except for how those variables can be accessed outside the class where they are defined, will there be any difference in how the object pointer should be assigned to them?

Comment: Ok, why do you need "*better* way of passing objects and storing them in private variables"? What exactly you don't like in that one above?

Comment: No, not that I don't like something. I am from Java background, where it is simple, just pass the object, and you are done. Here there are like myriads of ways, passing by pointer (like here), passing by reference, passing by assigning after defining custom copy constructor, etc. So asked whether this one is the best one for this purpose..